# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django'

Tags: python, django

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django'
```

How can I install Django?!?!?!

Comment: Don't just copy your error log. Describe the problem, state what you have done and what was expected.

Comment: `Permission denied` do you have write access to that directory? I believe you need root privileges to install django

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Comment: For the record, you don't need root to install Django

Comment: You should check out a django tutorial. It's highly recommended to install django in a virtual environment. Here's a step-by-step guide. https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_installation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have permission so install it locally using:

```
pip install django --user
```

This will install it in `.local` you have to append the variable `PYTHONPATH` with this.

Answer (score 2):

Install it either by:

`sudo pip install django` or like how @Y0da suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You might forgot to activate/install python virtual env. Same issue addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306440/oserror-errno-13-permission-denied-when-installing-django)

Answer (score 0):

Activate virtualenv(source env/bin/activate) and try installing again.